# OpenCV warpPerspective slow performance

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, homography

In my application:

1. I track an object.
2. Get where its `corners` are coming in this frame.
3. I find the homography between its `corners` from last frame and
   current frame.
4. Use that homography to do a `perspectiveTransform` on the `corners`
   found in the current frame, to get `transformed_corners`.
5. Use the `transformed_corners` to find the homography between them
   and the `overlay_image`.
6. Apply above homography `M` to `overlay_image`, to get what would be
   called the `warped_image` using warpPerspective. **This is the slow
   part**.
7. And then using masking operations, I print the `warped_image` onto the current frame where the object was found.

Now I know after reading [this blog article here](http://romsteady.blogspot.in/2015/07/calculate-opencv-warpperspective-map.html) why warpPerspective is slow.

And I'm getting ~300ms per frame in just the 6th step above, all because of warpPerspective. It's significantly affecting the FPS output of my application. Basically, it went down to 2FPS from 12 FPS without warping on every frame.

Is there any faster alternative to this? It's all done on Android, using NDK r9. What are some fast alternatives, and optimizations to reduce the warp time from 300ms to sub 50ms times?

Comment: what kind of interpolation method did you choose in warpPerspective? Do you allocate new memory in each warpPerspective call?

Comment: @Micka Not passing any flag values. So I suppose the default `INTER_LINEAR` is being used. [See here](https://dpaste.de/PWNL)

Comment: you could try `INTER_NEAREST` but from my experience it isn't much faster. Can you give some information about input/output images sizes etc? Maybe some code is necessary to tell whether there is any optimization possible.

Comment: The snippet I gave you is all that's relevant. Rest is declaration of empty `Mat`s and passing around from here and there. Image sizes vary from 1920x1080 for `currentFrame` and around 390x293 for `logoImage`. It's obvious that full HD res for currentFrame is too big. We tried smaller size, 960x540, and smaller, but time remains around ~250-350ms.

Comment: you warp from logo to currentFrame? Relevant for warping performance is only the resolution of the DESTINATION image. So if you know in advance that only a small part of the destination image is relevant, you can ignore the rest (e.g. forward-transform the bounding box of the source image to find the transformed bounding box in destination image). Btw, what `snippet` are you referring to? From the algorithm description it isn't visible whether you re-use an allocated `warped_image` and the chosen size of `warped_image` etc...

Comment: This dude https://dpaste.de/PWNL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91074/discussion-between-bad-keypoints-and-micka).

Comment: sorry, no time for intense chat. If currentFrame.size() is always the same and you reuse the destination matrix I don't see much optimization potential except warping to a smaller subimage only covering the transformed bounding box (which could give a lot of spee-up if the warped image is much smaller than the total frame).

Comment: @bad_keypoints did you ever find a way to optimize warpperspective?